# Get the field value by label time field as below.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the Hour and minute value from below control by using there **label**
also I want to set the value to that control.
Using jQuery and javascript.

```
<td class="ms-dttimeinput" nowrap="nowrap">
    <label for="ctl00_m_g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce_ff211_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateHours" style="display:none">NEndTime Hours</label>
    <select name="ctl00$m$g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce$ff211$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours" id="ctl00_m_g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce_ff211_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateHours">
        <option selected="selected" value="00:">00:</option>
        <option value="01:">01:</option>
        <option value="21:">21:</option>
        <option value="22:">22:</option>
        <option value="23:">23:</option>
    </select>&nbsp;

    <label for="ctl00_m_g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce_ff211_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateMinutes" style="display:none">NEndTime Minutes</label>
    <select name="ctl00$m$g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce$ff211$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes" id="ctl00_m_g_460bfeda_4d7a_4f5e_9587_9e0cd11d65ce_ff211_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateMinutes">
        <option selected="selected" value="00">00</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="35">35</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="55">55</option>
    </select></td>
```

Comment: Create two change events for each select, capture the selected value, combine, and show.

Comment: the "for" and "name" differ, so that's why the labels don't work. Also, why such a hideous long name?

Comment: @MightyPork -- That is ASP.NET's wonderful way of rendering HTML

Comment: @tymeJV give a try to PHP :P

Comment: @MightyPork `for` matches the `id`.

Comment: oh I see, sorry. It was so long that I didn't scroll to the end where the "id" is, and mistaken id and name...

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. You said "get the value", but what do you want to do with the value after you get it? And "set the value to that control" -- set the value of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value for hr and min using the text in the label tags

```
var hr,min;
$(".ms-dttimeinput label").each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this);
    if(lbl.text() == "NEndTime Hours")
        hr = lbl.next("select").val();
    if(lbl.text() == "NEndTime Minutes")
        min = lbl.next("select").val();
});
```

Set the value for hr and min using the text in the label tags

```
var hr = "01";
var min = "o5";
$(".ms-dttimeinput label").each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this);
    if(lbl.text() == "NEndTime Hours")
        lbl.next("select").val(hr);
    if(lbl.text() == "NEndTime Minutes")
        lbl.next("select").val(min);
});
```

If there is only one widget on the page the more practical approach would be using the class name selector "ms-dttimeinput" with the descendent tag selector " select" and the nth child class ":nth-child()".

```
var hr = $(".ms-dttimeinput select:nth-child(1)").val();
var min = $(".ms-dttimeinput select:nth-child(2)").val();

$(".ms-dttimeinput select:nth-child(1)").val(hr);
$(".ms-dttimeinput select:nth-child(2)").val(min);
```